Google service python API fails: is it a bad parameter (400) or a failed authentication (401)?
I'm working with the mybusinessbusinessinformation API, attempting to get a list of locations.
The documentation for this API is here.
I have already taken the following steps:

Filled out the form and basic setup
Gotten approval from Google's people
Generated an OAuth 2.0 secret and saved it to my local
Enabled the My Business Business Information API in my project's GCP console

Here is my code:
import os, json
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = "E:\\catphotos\catapultphotos\myhappysecret.json"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage'
,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/mybusiness.businessinformation']
TOKEN_FILE = 'token.json'

### Generate a credentials flow
def get_credentials():
    creds = None
    # Check if the token file exists
    if os.path.exists(TOKEN_FILE):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKEN_FILE, SCOPES)
    # If there are no valid credentials available, let the user log in
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKEN_FILE, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    return creds

### generate credentials, build service, pass account number for API
credentials = get_credentials()
service = build('mybusinessbusinessinformation','v1', credentials=credentials)
accountum = "999999999999"
output = service.accounts().locations().list(parent='accounts/%s' %accountnum, readMask='locations').execute()

When I execute this code, I get this error, which suggests that I'm mis-specifying a parameter, read_mask.

However when I click the hyperlink in the error response I get this error json, which suggests failed authentication:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.mybusiness.businessinformation.v1.Locations.ListLocations",
          "service": "mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

I know this is difficult to replicate because of the legwork necessary to set up, but I appreciate your guidance and thoughts of next paths.

have you tried it in google playgroud?

the readmask is not correct, use this  readMask = "storeCode,regularHours,name,languageCode,title,phoneNumbers,categories,storefrontAddress,websiteUri,regularHours,specialHours,serviceArea,labels,adWordsLocationExtensions,latlng,openInfo,metadata,profile,relationshipData,moreHours,serviceItems";
